Record Type Default Assignment
When I'm creating a record type, for the first record type, the "make it default" is disabled to edit and gets automatically checked when checking the "make it available" for profiles, and when creating the record, the choice for record type is not shown, as it automatically assigns the default(first record type), why this happens, and how to avoid this issue

welcome to SFSE, please see [ask] on getting the most from the Community. Your question could benefit from some screen shots (use [edit] )

This is just one of those things that Salesforce decides for us, and there's no way to alter that (standard) behavior.
The "Master" record type is special. It's a system-generated "record type" mainly for use when you haven't created any record types for a given SObject, and it's not treated the same as other record types.
Once you define your first record type for an SObject, you don't really have 2 record types per se. Salesforce wants you to only use your custom record type(s) at that point, so Salesforce isn't giving you a choice. The "Master" record type and any user-defined (i.e. custom) record types are mutually exclusive.
Since they're mutually exclusive, there is no choice for users to make about which record type they want to use and no choice for you to select a default until you make a second custom record type.
The only way the "Master" record type can co-exist with custom record types is if you don't make any custom record types available for a given profile (either through the creation screen when you make the record type, or later through modifying object settings for profiles and/or permission sets).

If a user doesn't have access to any custom record types, then they'll only be able to create records using the "Master" record type
If a user has access to even one custom record type, they can no longer create records using the "Master" record type
Creating a custom record type adds (or makes available) the RecordTypeId field for that SObject

I'm not sure if not having access to any custom record type would also prevent such users from accessing the RecordTypeId field. If they are prevented from doing that, then code and flows could break (if the code is being run in user mode or queries run with WITH USER_MODE). It's probably better to not tempt fate here and give everyone access to at least one custom record type instead of trying to mix the standard and custom behavior. You can, after all, functionally re-create the "Master" record type with a second custom record type.
